# running aws athena query via pyathena

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, pyathena

This query works fine in Athena's front-end:

```
SELECT * FROM analysisdata."iris" limit 10;
```

I am using this Python code to run the above query via Python/pyathena

```
from pyathena import connect

cursor = connect(aws_access_key_id='AKI.DELETED.2Q',
                 aws_secret_access_key='D.DELETED.Al',
                 s3_staging_dir='s3://Bla887342ac-a3ce-4600-94d0-9092f4a6bd20/Iris',
                 region_name='eu-west-1').cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM analysisdata.""iris"" limit 10;""")

print(cursor.description)
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
pyathena.error.DatabaseError: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 1:27: mismatched input '.' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'APPROXIMATE', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT'}
```

I presume is my introduction of:

```
""" and ""
```

Any ideas?

PS:

I tried:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM analysisdata.""iris"" limit 10;")
```

get:

```
pyathena.error.OperationalError: com.facebook.presto.hive.DataCatalogException: Namespace analysisdata not found. Please check your query.
```

Why does facebook appear in this?

I also tried:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM analysisdata.iris limit 10;")
```

same error message ...

Comment: The error seems related to the period (.). By the way, why are you inserting all those quotes? Why not just use `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM analysisdata.iris limit 10;")`?

Comment: The original Athena query contains quotes ...

Comment: Yes, but it probably works without them.

Comment: OK thanks will give this a go.

Comment: I updated my question ...

Comment: when you say you got same error for cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM analysisdata.iris limit 10;") , which error are you referring to ??? because you have two errors in the question.

Comment: The error in the PS section sorry

Comment: Are you certain you're on the same region? It seems that your catalog in eu-west-1 does not contain analysisdata db

Comment: when I browse my s3 bucket it says EU (Ireland) so I am pretty sure eu-west-1 is correct?

Comment: @TewfikGhariani actually you were right. It appears as if the s3 and bucket regions have to aligned. You may post answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it appears, your catalog in eu-west-1 does not contain analysisdata db.

You have to specify the region in which you created the database/table in Athena Console, rather than the specified S3 bucket region.

To solve that, log into the console, and verify which region contains your database/table.